# Where to Specify Firebase Stuffs in React Native Project structure

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, react-native, react-native-ios

am creating react native application and have to use firebase database in it.

So, I go through the firebase console and for react-native development I choose the **WEB** option instead of Android and IOS.

So, I got as below :

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.4.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzcSyGByfEez587Lor799jeyJRnFYH0z1yu354",
    authDomain: "fir-app-69dcx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://fir-app-69dcx.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "fir-app-69dcx",
    storageBucket: "fir-app-69dcx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "5548741593"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

Its saying that : 
**Click Copy, then paste the code snippet into your application HTML**

Am using Visual Studio IDE for development.

I have confused that where can I add this above firebase stuffs in my React native Project structure ?

Thanks.

Comment: Could this site help you, perhaps?
[rnfirebase.io](https://rnfirebase.io/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a nice tuto I've followed [here](https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-react-native-and-redux-course) I've do this :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { Header, Button, Spinner } from './components/common';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';


class App extends Component {
    state = { loggedIn: null };

    componentWillMount() {
        firebase.initializeApp({
            apiKey: 'stuff',
            authDomain: 'stuff',
            databaseURL: 'stuff',
            projectId: 'stuff',
            storageBucket: 'stuff',
            messagingSenderId: 'stuff'
        });

        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
            } else {
                this.setState({ loggedIn: false });
            }
        });
    }

    renderContent() {
        switch (this.state.loggedIn) {
            case true:
                return (
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', paddingTop: 5 }}>
                        <Button onPress={() => firebase.auth().signOut()}>
                            Log out
                        </Button>
                    </View>
                );
            case false:
                return <LoginForm />;
            default:
                return (
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', paddingTop: 5 }}>
                        <Spinner />
                    </View>
                );
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Header headerText="Authentification" />
                    {this.renderContent()}
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```